# Declaring variable as i vs &i in the foreach loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, foreach, ampersand

Why do these loops give the same output:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> ar = {2, 3 ,4};
    for(auto i: ar) //this line changes in the next loop
        cout<<i<<" ";

    cout<<"\n";

    for(auto &i: ar) //i changed to &i
        cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

They both give the same output:

> 2 3 4

> 2 3 4

When declaring the foreach loop variable, shouldn't adding ampersand make the variable take the references of the values in the array, and printing i make it print the references. What is happening here?

By print the references I meant something like this code prints:

```
for(auto i: ar)
    cout<<&i<<" ";
```

Output:

> 0x61fdbc 0x61fdbc 0x61fdb

Comment: What do you think should be printed by "print the references"?

Comment: Now test `std::cout << &i << " ";` in both cases.

Comment: References are not pointers, they're aliases. By printing the reference, you print the actual value that is being referenced

Comment: @Jarod42, I did. now both of them print values starting with 0x... Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes can you explain what you mean by aliases? Maybe direct me to a resource where I can learn more about this..

Comment: `std::cout << &i` prints the address of `i`. which is the address of local variable in case of `auto i : ar`, and the address of element from vector with `auto& i : ar`.

Comment: A reference is just a new name for an existing variable/object. They are sometimes implemented as pointers, but they don't behave as such. Not sure if it's what you need, but try looking [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: Why do you expect different output when using a reference? A reference behaves just as the referenced object, did you maybe confuse references with pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are the same because in the first loop you copy the variable's value in a new variable `i` and print its value. (Additional RAM allocated)

In the second loop you access the value of the current element from the memory by assigning its address to `i`. (No additional RAM allocated)

On the other side:

```
cout<<&i<<" ";
```

causes printing the address of `i`.

Comment: Hi Lyuboslav - This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: About that RAM Usage: this maybe a little overstated: https://godbolt.org/z/Y3xTh6

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand operator has many purposes. These two of the many are hard to recognize, namely the `&` infront of a variable in a declaration ( such as `int& i` ( or `int &i`, same thing ) ), and the `&` infront of a variable not in a declaration, such as `cout << &i`.

Try these and you will get a better understanding.

```
for (auto i : ar)
    cout << i << " "; // 2 3 4 // element of ar
    
for (auto &i : ar)
    cout << i << " "; // 2 3 4 // element of ar

for (auto i : ar)
    cout << &i << " "; // address of local variable i (probably same address)
    
for (auto &i: ar)
    cout << &i << " "; // address of elements of ar (increasing addresses)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This clears up some things. One question: What is the difference between the first two loops in the code? What did adding ampersand change?

Comment: @Neon, in the first example i is a copy of a value in ar, where in the second i is a reference to a value in ar.